# Delete duplicate entries while keeping one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table but it has no unique ID or primary key.

It has 3 columns in total.

| name | user_id | role_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ben | 1 | 2 |
| ben | 1 | 2 |
| sam | 1 | 3 |

I'd like to remove one entry with the name Ben.

So output would look like this

| name | user_id | role_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ben | 1 | 2 |
| sam | 1 | 3 |

Most of the examples shows deleting duplicate entries with ID or primary key. However how would I retain one entry whilest removing the other ones?

Using the following query I was able to get duplicated rows

```
SELECT name, user_id, role_id, count(*) FROM some_table
GROUP BY name, user_id, role_id
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

To clarify, I am looking to delete these rows.

Prefer not creating a new table.

Comment: Make a unique key with all the columns.

Comment: please clarify if you want to actually delete a row from the database or just not have it appear in a select.  please clarify what makes a row a duplicate: is it all columns being identical?  if not, please clarify how you want to choose which row to keep.

Comment: if all you want is to select rows with no duplicates, `select distinct name, user_id, role_id from some_table`

Comment: [This might help](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/).  Read the example using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Comment: Updated the main question. I actually want to delete the rows itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to worry about other users accessing the table -

```sql
CREATE TABLE `new_table` AS
SELECT DISTINCT `name`, `user_id`, `role_id`
FROM `old_table`;

RENAME TABLE
    `old_table` TO `backup`,
    `new_table` TO `old_table`;
```

Or you could use your duplicates query to output lots of single row delete queries -

```sql
SELECT
    `name`,
    `user_id`,
    `role_id`,
    COUNT(*),
    CONCAT('DELETE FROM some_table WHERE name=\'', `name`, '\' AND user_id=\'', `user_id`, '\' AND role_id=\'', `role_id`, '\' LIMIT 1;') AS `delete_stmt`
FROM `some_table`
GROUP BY `name`, `user_id`, `role_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Or you could temporarily add a SERIAL column and then remove it after the delete -

```sql
ALTER TABLE `some_table` ADD COLUMN `temp_id` SERIAL;

DELETE `t1`.* 
FROM `some_table` `t1`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(`temp_id`) `min_temp_id`
    FROM `some_table`
    GROUP BY `name`, `user_id`, `role_id`
) `t2` ON `t1`.`temp_id` = `t2`.`min_temp_id`
WHERE `t2`.`min_temp_id` IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE `some_table` DROP COLUMN `temp_id`;
```

Comment: if it is a large table moving the entire table or adding a column is a more expensive operation than just deleting the subset from the table and reinserting them

Comment: @DetroitMike I totally agree. Context is everything. If this is a really large table then creating a DISTINCT copy of it might carry significant overhead, especially if it is a table with lots of text content. I was not suggesting anything wrong with your answer, just proposing alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are not saving anything by not having a primary key; mysql (at least with innodb) requires a primary key and will create a hidden one if you do not have one.  So I would first add a primary key:

```
alter table some_table add id serial primary key;
```

Then you can easily remove duplicates with:

```
delete a from some_table a join some_table b on a.name=b.name and a.user_id=b.user_id and a.role_id=b.role_id and b.id < a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take the duplicate records and put them into another table.

```
SELECT  
   name, 
   user_id, 
   role_id
   INTO some_new_table
FROM some_table
GROUP BY name, user_id, role_id
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Then you can delete those records from your source table

```
DELETE a
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_new_table b
  ON a.name = b.name
    AND a.user_id = b.user_id
    AND a.role_id = b.role_id
```

Finally you can then insert the deduped records back into your table.

```
INSERT INTO some_table 
SELECT 
  name, 
  user_id, 
  role_id
FROM some_new_table
```

If the volume of dupes is very large you could also just create a new table with the deduped data. Truncate \ Drop the old table and then Insert \ Rename from the new table.

Comment: Wouldn't you have duplicate values in some_new_table? I think you need to use DISTINCT in the first Query.

Comment: no - because you are doing group by all columns in the table which is the same as doing distinct.